# Fraction Word Problem

Tags: contest-math

A computer virus destroys computer memory. On the first day, it destroyed half of this memory. On the second day, it destroyed a third of the memory remaining after the first day; on the 3rd day, it destroyed a fourth of the memory remaining after two days, and on the fourth day, it destroyed a fifth of the memory remaining after 3 days. What part of of all the computer memory was left after those four days?

Comment: Think telescoping product.

Comment: Or much easier $\frac 45*\frac 34*\frac 23 *\frac 12$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Day one you have $\frac{1}{2}$ your memory remaining

Day two you have $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{2}{3}$ of your memory remaining.

Day four you have $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{5}$  of your memory remaining.